# Login with another username MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.0 and I created a new user in my database:

```
create user 'johann'@'localhost' identified by 'johann22';
grant select on jewellery.customers to 'johann'@'localhost';
```

Now I'd like to connect as that new user but every time a quit MySQL, the command directly prompt me the password of 'root'

I have already tried to connect with root then connect to as the new user using this code:

```
-u johann -p johann22;
```

but it says that I have a syntax error.

Comment: Open a terminal and write `mysql -u johann -p johann22`, then hit Enter

Comment: @Hackerman not recognized as an internal command :/

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 on MyBootCamp

Comment: Maybe you dont have the mysql.exe file in your PATH variable....try writing the full path to the mysql.exe file instead.

Comment: Now it's good, it changed the path using this code set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;%PATH%

Comment: Glad to help pal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-u johann -p johann22;` is not an SQL command you can run in the mysql client. Those are command-line options for the mysql client.

So you would run this in your shell (not in the mysql client):

```
mysql -u johann -pjohann22
```

Also notice that you must NOT have a space between `-p` and the password. If you have a space, the `-p` means to prompt you for a password, then the word following the space (`johann22`) is the name of the database.